# Can't get count down timer to have 100th of seconds

Tags: java

I have a count down timer that works fine except for I'm geting numbers that have more then 2 digits for the 100th of seconds.   I'm creating 2 calendar objects, bgetting there time alue in milli secons, and subtracting it. code

```
    long milsecs1= calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long milsecs2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();

    long diff = milsecs2 - milsecs1;
    long dsecs = diff / 1000;

    long ddays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);  
    diff=diff-ddays *(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
    textDays.setText(   Integer.toString( (int)ddays)+":" );

    long dhours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    diff=diff-dhours* (60 * 60 * 1000);
    textHours.setText(   Integer.toString( (int)dhours)+":" );

    long dminutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
    diff=diff-dminutes* (60 * 1000);
    textMinuts.setText(   Integer.toString( (int)dminutes)+":" );

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// THIS IS THE PART THAT IS NOT WORKING, I WANT NUMBERS 0-99, BUT GETTING NUMBERS LIKE 230
    long dseconds = diff / (100);
    textSeconds.setText(   Integer.toString( (int)dseconds)+":" );
    diff=diff-dseconds;
```

Comment: Look up the `%` operator in your Java reference.

Comment: And keep in mind that you're starting with a milliseconds value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) provides a much simpler (and thoroughly proven) solution in its [Period class](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html). Something like this should do the trick (untested):

```
Period period = new Period(calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), calendar2.getTimeInMillis());
int days = period.getDays();
int hours = period.getHours();
... etc.
```